# I am getting an error regarding mssql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, sql-server

Please help to cure this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_real_escape_string() in
```

The Code:

```
<?php
$host="-Removed-"; // Host name
$username="-Removed-"; // Mysql username
$password="-Removed-"; // Mysql password
$db_name="-Removed-"; // Database name
$tbl_name="USERPASS";
$tbl_name2="EMPLOYEES"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mssql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mssql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['login'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mssql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mssql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT *
  FROM $tbl_name U, $table_name2 E 
  WHERE U.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
  AND USERNAME='$myusername' 
  AND PASSWORD='$mypassword'";
$result=mssql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mssql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

.

Thank You for the help! Been trying to figure this out for forever now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using MSSQL Server there is no mssql_real_escape_string, only MySQL and MySQLi have it, at least I didn't find it:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of a MSSQL equivalent?

Comment: You're welcome. Try search for "vollmer at ampache dot org 02-Oct-2006 03:52" in http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php, he wrote a function for that

Comment: There is also PDO (PHP Data Objects) which can connect to all the databases PHP supports, BUT MSSQL is experimental. :)

Comment: Have you thought about migrating? To MySQL or PostgreSQL? :D

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot migrate at this time.

Answer (score 2):

That's because thereisn't any php function called `mssql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of right now, PHP mssql extension neither supports [parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements) nor has an escape function. You have to either write your own escape function or use something like [PDO prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection.